# Foreign keys in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

i´ve got a problem with foreign keys, it´s an strange problem.

First table:

```
CREATE TABLE adjunto
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  codigo text,
  descripcion text,
  usuario integer,
  file integer,
  nombre text,
  propiedades hstore,

  CONSTRAINT adjunto_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
  CONSTRAINT adjunto_file_fkey FOREIGN KEY (file)
      REFERENCES file (file_id) MATCH SIMPLE 
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
) WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Second table:

```
CREATE TABLE adjunto_coleccion_privada
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  adjunto integer,
  coleccion integer,
  CONSTRAINT adjunto_coleccion_privada_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
  CONSTRAINT adjunto_coleccion_privada_adjunto_fkey FOREIGN KEY (adjunto)
  REFERENCES adjunto (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT adjunto_coleccion_privada_coleccion_fkey FOREIGN KEY (coleccion)
  REFERENCES coleccion (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Command:

```
INSERT INTO adjunto_coleccion_privada (adjunto, coleccion) 
VALUES (600, 2) RETURNING id
```

Values 600 and 2 exist in both tables, adjunto and colecion.

Detailed error:

```
Mensaje: ERROR: insert or update on table "adjunto_coleccion_privada" 
                violates foreign key   
                constraint "adjunto_coleccion_privada_adjunto_fkey"
Detail: Key (adjunto)=(600) is not present in table "adjunto".
```

Comment: Did you double check that 600 is in `adjunto` ? What is the content of those 2 tables ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Postgres is not lying. You don't have a row in adjunto with that ID

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code (I dropped the `adjunto_coleccion_privada_coleccion_fkey` constraint since referred table does not exist in your pasted code).

I see no problem at all.

Are you really sure that there is a record with `id` = 600 in the `adjunto` table?